# Hardhat doesn't recognize custom errors from inherited Contracts

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, testing, chai, custom-errors

I am trying to test `TimelockController` contract from Openzeppelin using their test.

The timelockController [imports](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/ebc90e893e1abf0e602e0be702f37d20e650407a/contracts/governance/TimelockControllerUpgradeable.sol#L9) `Address.sol`, which has a custom Error called `FailedCall`.
Now for my case, I have created my own `TimelockController` just by inheriting this OZ `TimelockController`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/governance/TimelockControllerUpgradeable.sol";

contract PushTimelockController is TimelockControllerUpgradeable {

    function initialize(
        uint256 minDelay,
        address[] memory proposers,
        address[] memory executors,
        address admin
    ) public initializer {
        __TimelockController_init(minDelay, proposers, executors, admin);
    }
}
```

The problem now is while expecting some functions to revert with custom error `FailedCall` using this syntax:

```
await expect(
            this.mock
              .connect(this.executor)
              .executeBatch(
                operation.targets,
                operation.values,
                operation.payloads,
                operation.predecessor,
                operation.salt,
              ),
          ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(this.mock, 'FailedCall');
        })
```

where `this.mock` is the `PushTimelockController`, hardhat is unable to locate the custom error, throwing this error:

```
Error: The given contract doesn't have a custom error named 'FailedCall'
```

This might be because my `PushTimelockController` is inheriting `TimelockController` which is again inheriting from `Address.sol`, and hardhat is unable to read the custom errors defined in `Address.sol`.

What can be a workaround? Do I need to get a contract instance of `Address.sol` just for the errors or is there any other way?